# default start reputaion at stackoverflow for new users?

Tags: feedback, user-feedback

i want to know what is the default start reputaion at stackoverflow for new users?
BTW i studied informatics and recievied an excelent diploma (needs only 3 years for it) but i disagreed with some here. they downvoted me. 
sad. seems not a fair place here for beginner. not tolorant place for new  users with unusual answers. and they gave me not the chance to answer - often (becouse topic fast closed they technically restricted me). so my conclusion: not a fair place for new users and you dont get normal users by waiting. and if you work or develop at isolated section of programming the meanstrem people her downgrad you fast with now chance justify/explain for you. good place for collect answer. bad place to start helping people. thats was my feedback (or may a goodbye) from a new and frustrated users with informatics diploma.

Comment: The answer to your question in the title is: 1.

Comment: so its anwerd. i tried to change status to anserd. i cant. restricted  :D

Comment: please don't offer an answer-Input-box during its restricted! its really doesn't makes any sense!

Comment: [meta] is the place for these sorts of questions (but do try to separate them into different and specific questions, unless you're just trying to vent, which probably won't be taken well). We perhaps don't explain downvotes as often as we should, but a quick read of the [help] should explain most cases. If you don't understand why a post of yours is getting many downvotes, you can always ask **about that specific post** on Meta (a single downvote probably isn't worth looking into - one single person doesn't necessarily represent the community as a whole).

Comment: thanksBut: not working suggestion. i tried. result: "You must have at least 5 reputation on Stack Overflow to ask a question on meta."